# Get-Service returns service from source machine, not remote machine

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, services

I have:

- My local machine
- Remote machine one (foo1.bin.com)
- Remote machine two (foo2.bin.com)

I have the following piece of code:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName foo2.bin.com
```

When I run this code from my local machine as my own user, I am unable to start it because it tells me I might need additional rights. If I login into `foo1.bin.com` with a different user (functional user) and run the same piece of code, it seems to work. It displays all the services, including status.

**The problem is**, when I run this from `foo1.bin.com`, I am expecting to see all the services from `foo2.bin.com`. Instead, I am seeing all services from `foo1.bin.com`. Why is that, and how do I get the services from the second server?

Comment: Is your foo1 account an admin? You shouldn't ignore the message about the need for additional rights.

Comment: If that really is the computername then you should quote it as `'foo2.bin.com'`

Comment: Check the MachineName property to make sure you're looking at the right thing when running from foo1 to foo2 like: `Get-Service -ComputerName 'foo2.bin.com' | Select MachineName,Status,Name`. Powershell won't return the wrong computer's services unless it believes the local machine is both foo1 and foo2. Try pinging foo1/foo2 and confirm they resolve to different IPs.

Comment: can try  `Invoke-Command -Computername "foo2.bin.com" -ScriptBlock { Get-Service }`